# How to add asterisk symbol in required Field

Tags: javascript, css, polymer-1.0, polymer-3.x

I have to add asterisk symbol(*) on required field how can I do this in polymer .
`<paper-input id="firstNameText" required label="First Name" ></paper-input>`

Comment: If it were me I'd probably just use css and a pseudo class with the attribute selector to the element like `paper-input[required]:before { content: "*"; display: inline; color: red; }` and be done with it, but I'm not sure if you're looking for something more specific so just leaving as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Check [paper-input](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/@polymer/paper-input)

You have there some information about it

> --paper-input-container-label-after: Mixin applied to label after pseudo element (useful for required asterisk)   {}

Note that you would have to use paper-input-container also

Might this work?:

```
element {
   --paper-input-container-label-after: {
       your properties for adding *
   };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the paper-input tag:
placeholder="*"
With CSS you can style the placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

The `paper-input` has both a prefix and a suffix slot, so you can add a `span` or even another Polymer element into the slot.

```
<paper-input id="firstNameText" label="First Name">
  <span class="colourRed" slot="prefix">*</span>
</paper-input>

<paper-input id="surnameText" label="Surname">
  <required-element slot="suffix"></required-element>
</paper-input>
```

If you want to use the required attribute, you would do something along the lines of the following:

```
<paper-input auto-validate
             char-counter
             class="fillWidth100Percent"
             error-message="Please enter a name."
             invalid="{{invalid.FirstName}}"
             label="First Name"
             maxlength="255"
             required
             value="{{firstName}}">
    <required-element slot="suffix">
    </required-element>
</paper-input>
```

Note that the `required-element` would be a custom element.